# Transparent circle in QGIS

Tags: qgis, circle

What to do to only center of the circle became transparent?
also I want see the red outline *

[image]

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the circle symbol, you can set the outline to be red, but in the Fill section, adjust the transparency (opacity) slider. The rest of the symbol will not be affected by this change - just the fill.

[image: changing symbol fill transparency]